# Read multiple strings from file

Tags: c, c-strings

Having trouble figuring this out, trying to fscanf two names into two char[]

```
if (numpairs == 2){
            fscanf("%s %s", malename1[MAX], malename2[MAX]); //read in names 
            printf("%s %s", malename1[MAX], malename2[MAX]); //print out names
```

this is were it crashes and gives me "waring:warning: passing argument 1 of 'fscanf' from incompatible pointer type

EDIT: MAX is defined as 20, and malename1[MAX+1] malename2[MAX+1] (+1 to account for null)

EDIT: I've got the read in working somewhat, how can account for a space to end the read in of malename1? I'm reading in Chris for malename1 and Ryan for malename2 but for malename1 it scans ChrisRyan

Comment: Can you show the definitions of malename1, malename2, and MAX?

Answer (score 1):

The first argument to `fscanf()` is a `FILE*`, not a `char*`.

Assuming you meant to use `scanf()`, the code is attempting to treat a `char` as a `char[]` (assuming `malename1` and `malename2` have type `char[]`, as stated). Change to:

```
scanf("%s %s", malename1, malename2);
printf("%s %s", malename1, malename2);
```

or if `fscanf()`:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %s", malename1, malename2); /* where 'fp' is a valid 'FILE*'. */
```

Note you could also add a maximum length to be read to prevent buffer overruns:

```
fscanf(fp, "%20s %20s", malename1, malename2); /* Read max of 20 chars. */
```

Comment: I forgot my file pointer, wow... hah, any ideas on the space questions I posted?

Comment: Can you double-check the content of the file? The space should act as a delimiter and be skipped for the next input.

Comment: In the file the names are "Chris Ryan" exactly, with the space

Comment: @Ryan, I am unsure why this is not working. Just double-checked with a file here and using `sscanf()` here: http://ideone.com/w4NOA

Answer (score 0):

If `malename1` and `malename2` are strings of type `char *`. Then the required statement should be:

```
fscanf(fp, "%s %s", malename1, malename2); //fp is file pointer
```

http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/clibrary/cstdio/fscanf/